# How to clear form data jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to clear all form input data after a submitting all input data to php file how can I clear this data by using jquery function?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please vist the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Assuming you ajax the form, have `$("#formID")[0].reset()` in the success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the submit event and then clear the values of each input like below:

```js
$('#form').submit(function() {
  $(this)[0].reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: But there is a not just text even there is a checkbox file upload time and date input so how to resolve this?

Comment: And may be val function is using for getting a value of input field.

Comment: you can use the reset function on the form.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the form to reset *before* it actually submits? The submit event handler gets called before submission occurs.

Comment: But if we are using .val("")  than may be it possible

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```js
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  var children = $(this).children()
  children.each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).attr('type') === 'checkbox') return $(el).removeAttr('checked')
    $(el).val(null)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <br>
  <input type="text" />
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" />iphone
  <input type="checkbox" />Android
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>Male
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
  <br>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button type="submit"> submit </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#my_form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.querySelector(".name").value = "";
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" class="name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then the input value will be always empty

Comment: The question asked about clearing the form *after* submitting. This empties the `name` field *before* submitting.

Comment: Also it is not jQuery

Comment: It is a not a major issue that it is a jquery or javascript I just want to finish my work by using jquery or either javascript.

Comment: Oh,just change it `let` > `var`,cause most of my project are staring using ES6 syntax,sorry about that